# Fear is the enemy of will, but what is the enemy of fear? (And the rest of the emotional spectrum)

Tags: dc, green-lantern

As Hal Jordan says,

> Fear is the enemy of will

(*Justice League - Doom* 2012)

This is, as far as I'm aware, a recurring theme across DC continuities. The Sinestro Corps (or Yellow Lanterns) has a significant advantage over the Green Lanterns because fear neutralizes willpower. (Please correct me if I'm wrong, of course.)

But fear and will are not the only emotions to fuel lantern powers. There is also rage (red), greed (orange), hope (blue), compassion (indigo), and love (violet). Do any of these pairs have a similar relationship as will and fear, where one has an advantage over the other? Which one, if any, has an advantage over fear?

Comment: Ironically, this is almost the opposite of the sentiment expressed in [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126399/why-is-fear-good-in-the-dark-knight-rises) that was just asked.

Comment: Fear > Will > Hate > Anger > Suffering > Fear.
Source: George Lucas

Answer (score 4):

The 7 emotions of the emotional spectrum are the same as the ROYGBIV spectrum
If we take green as being the middle then the rest have an opposite. Working on this the Blue/Hope ring will be a counter to Yellow/Fear.

This makes sense as hope would naturally be the counter of fear.

Blue rings can defeat Yellow constructs.  <sub>**Green Lantern Vol 4 #41**</sub> .

Blue also counters Orange / Greed with Oranges Avarice having no effect over Blue lanterns  <sub>**Green Lantern Vol 4 #36**</sub>   & Red / Rage  <sub>**Green Lantern Vol 4 #38**</sub>  .

Indigo / Compassion is the opposite to Orange / Greed so we can speculate that they would have a counter effect based on their position on both the light and emotional spectrums.

and

Violet / Love is the opposite to Red / Rage and again we can speculate that they would counter based on their position on both the light and emotional spectrums.

Blue is pretty powerful but needs other rings to actually do anything, acting as a booster to the other rings

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: @jpmc26 just speculation based on the order of colour in the light spectrum and known relationships between blue and other colours which was in Green Lantern volume 4 #36, #38 and #41

Comment: In Green Lantern Vol 4 #38, a blue ring is placed on a Red Lantern Hal Jordan's finger and it reverses the effects of the ring and cures him. There is no direct relationship between their vulnerabilities and where their letter falls in ROYGBIV. Heck, the Green in the center would have no opposite if what you're saying is true.